# Profile issue : Agent-1 can see the Health Tab, but Agent-2 cant see the Health tab, though they are under single profile?

Tags: profile, custom-profile

I have a **Profile-A** in my `salesforce` org and under that profile I have two users, `Agent-1` and `Agent-2`. `Agent-1` is able to **Health Custom tab**, but `Agent-2` unable to see **Health Custom tab**. Could anyone please guide me what could be the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution of the issue. Since Agent-1 was successfully able to see the Health Tab and Agent-2 was not. because Heath tab was not added in the selected layout.

This is user specific setting whether user wants to see those tabs or not. The setting can be done using
My Setting --> Display & Layout --> Customized My Tabs and add that tab.

Answer (score 2):

`Agent-2` may have overridden the tabs with their own personal customisations.

If so, I suspect they will still be able to get to "`Health Custom`" after clicking the "`+`" icon in the tab list.

If so, when adding the tab, you should tick the box asking whether you want to "`Overwrite users' personal tab customizations`"

Comment: @user4567570 so I believe my answer is basically correct. You've decided not to "Overwrite users' personal tab customizations" and will let the user customise their tabs themselves. In both cases, the crux of the issue is around personal tab customisations. Are you please able to mark this as the answer if it has helped you.